# VBA to copy rows from one sheet to another using 3 criteria

Tags: vba

I'm trying to use a VBA to search in the sheet of one workbook "Transactional Files" and copy to a sheet in the workbook "Utilities" based on three criteria.  The first one is, If column A="PV", the second criteria is if column M has either "Utilities-Water" "Utilities-Electric" or "Utilities Gas", and the third one is if column AE isn't already in the sheet, then copy and paste the row if all three are met.

I found this template, but not sure where to plug in my criteria:

```
Sub copyRow()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lastrowDest As Long, currowSrc As Long, currowDest As Long, lastrowSrc 
As Long
Dim critvalue1 As String

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet1")

lastrowSrc = ws2.Range("AE" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row - 1
lastrowDest = ws1.Range("AE" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For currowSrc = 2 To lastrowSrc
critvalue1 = ws2.Range("E" & currowSrc).Value
ws2.Cells(6, 5).Value = critvalue1
For currowDest = 2 To lastrowDest
    If ws1.Range("E" & currowDest).Value = critvalue1 Then
       ws2.Rows(currowSrc).Copy Destination:=ws1.Range("A" & currowDest)
    End If
Next currowDest
Next currowSrc

 End Sub
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The example code you gave is from one sheet to another. 
You want to check one sheet in one workbook, to another sheet in A DIFFERENT WORKBOOK.

So you'll have to open that workbook (And when done close it).

Then you'll look up row by row inside our sheet

```
Dim trx as workbook ' the other workbook (i.e. the other excel file). 
' trx is a vba variable that will hold the contents of the transactions excel file
' a workbook has sheets in it. 
dim sheet1 as worksheet, sheet2 as worksheet 
' these are two vba variables holding the two sheets we'll work on. 
dim criteria1 as boolean, criteria2 as boolean, criteria3 as boolean
' boolean variables can have the value of True or False only. 

' just for reading 
dim columnAindex as integer, columnMindex as integer, columnAEindex as integer

columnAindex = 1
columnMindex = Range("1M").column ' 13
columnAEindex = Range("AE").column ' yup, that number
set trx = Workbooks.open("trx.xlsx")
set sheet2 = trx.Sheets(1) ' or whatever sheet by index or name.

For Each myrow in Rows 
    criteria1 = (myrow.cells(1,columnAindex) = "PV') ' .cells(1,1) is columnA of current row
    m = myrow.cells(1, columnMindex) ' value in cell of this current row, at column M
    criteria2 = ( (m = this) or (m = that) or (m = theother) )
    ' if the value in AE is unique for each row, this will work:
    ' I got that from another question on stack overflow   
    ae = myrow.cells(1, columnAEindex) ' value in our row at column AE
    set trxAEcolumnRange = sheet2.Range("AE:AE")
    criteria3 = IsError(Application.Match(ae, trxAEcolumnRange, 0)) ' true if could not find a match to the value in our row's ae. 


    if criteria1 and criteria2 and criteria3 then copypasterow(myrow)
next 
trx.close()
end sub

sub CopyPasteRow(aRow)
    aRow.copy
    sheet2.range.end.paste ' no need for xlup because this is the next empty row after the data
end sub
```

Comment: I've edited my first post to show what I entered, but am getting an error.  I'm sure I've inputted something incorrectly.  Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Hi kong. Put the question back to the way it was. Then just add a remark HERE that the code I wrote is not working, and I'll fix it.

Debug your program to see what exactly is failing. Is it opening the file?  
Are you getting a compile error?  What exactly is wrong?  

In any case, did I understand the criteria3 correctly?  Or are you a student who got some homework and yourself don't really understand the question?

Comment: I edited your question back to the original, and hope that's accepted. I'll check the code and see WHAT EXACTLY does not work, although I suspect that there are no serious problems. Read the code and tell me, HERE, REPLYING TO MY COMMENT, which lines of code you don't understand, or where the program is failing by you.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  No, I'm just an accountant trying to streamline a process that seems too manual.  I really am not good with using VBA, and need apply more time to learning it and the logic that goes with it.  I do not understand in this code where it is defining the worksheets and pages to run the script.  That's probably really elementary and I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: I'll edit the code and add comments. Comments start with a single quote mark at the beginning of a line, or after a command.